# Java ExecutorService for Async web service

Tags: multithreading, web-services, asynchronous, callback, executorservice

We need to implement a Async web service.

- **Behaviour of web service:**

We send the request for an account to server and it sends back the sync response with an acknowledgement ID. After that we get multiple Callback requests which contains that acknowldegment ID. The last callback request for an acknowledgement ID will contain a text(completed:true) in the response which will tell us that this is the last callback request for that account and acknowledgement ID. This will help us to know that async call for a particular account is completed and we can mark its final status. We need to execute this web service for multiple accounts. So, we will be getting callback requests for many accounts.

- **Question:**

What is the optimal way to process these multiple callback requests coming for multiple accounts.

- **Solutions that we thought of:**
- ExecutorService Fixed Thread Pool: This will parallely process our callback requests but the concern is that it does not maintain the sequence. So it will be difficult for us to determine that the last callback request for an acknowledgment ID(account) has come. Hence, we will not be able to mark the final status of that account as completed with surity.
- ExecutorService Single Thread Executor: Here, only one thread is there in the pool with an unbouded queue. If we use this then processing will be pretty slow as only one thread will be actually processing.

Please suggest an optimal way to implement requirement both memory and performance wise.

Answer (score 2):

Let's be clear about one thing: HTTP is a blocking, synchronous protocol.  Request/response pairs aren't asynch.  What you're doing is spawning asynch requests and returning to the caller to let them know the request is being processed (HTTP 200) or not (HTTP 500).

I'm not sure that I know optimal for this situation, but there are other considerations:

1. Use an `ExecutorServiceThreadPool` that you can configure.  Make sure you have a prefix that lets you distinguish these threads from others.
2. Add request task to a blocking dequeue and have a pool of consumer threads process them.  You can tune the dequeue and the consumer thread pool sizes.
3. If processing is intensive, send request messages to a queue running on another server.  Have a pool of queue listeners process the requests.

You cannot assume that the callbacks will return in a certain order.  Don't depend on "last" being "true".  You'll have to join all those threads together to know when they're finished.

It sounds like the web service should have a URL that lets users query for status.

Comment: Webservice does not have URLto tell it has send all the callbacks.Also even if they tell us they have send us all, still our final status will depend on whether we have received all of them or not.That is why we want to proceed with ExecutorService Fixed Thread Pool but it appears we should go with ExecutorService Single Thread Executor.

Comment: Add one.  You return false if they haven't all come back; that's the idea.  The thread pool won't change that.